# No hats on mobile

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, ios-app, winter-bash, winter-bash-2015

I've scarcely touched my laptop over the winter break, satisfying my SO addiction entirely through the iOS app. (And occasionally the mobile website.) It's been a great exercise in seeing how livable the app is (and posting app bug/feature questions to MSO).

Apparently I'm earning hats, and interacting with folks who've achieved even greater feats of haberdashery, but I don't get to see any of it.

The end of Winter Bash 2014 is near, sadly, but perhaps we could consider including mobile users in the fun next year?

Comment: Not sure what we'll do next year, but definitely not nothing.

Comment: @BrianNickel Well, that's *something*. :)

Comment: I am facing the same, except that I switch to the full site even though I am on a mobile browser just to see the hats.

Comment: As some of the hats require you to use a mobile platform, it makes since that you should also be able to see them from there as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is fixed in 1.4.1 (released Friday).

Hats are read-only in the iOS app.  They are displayed in the user list, on profiles, and on questions and answers.  By default if you've not opted-in or out on a particular site, you will see things with the default site setting (e.g. no hats on SO, yes on MSE).

You can turn hats off just for the app under the menu in About.  This does not opt you in or out on the site.

**Disclaimers:**

1. This did not get nearly the amount of testing I would hope for and is using a surprisingly flakey SVG renderer.  If your hat doesn't appear I'm really sorry.
2. If WinterBash breaks the app, I may pull the plug on the whole thing.
3. This is an extremely limited integration, there's no chance to get out a new build and there's very little I can actually fix.

**Screenhots**

[image: Hats in questions]

[image: Hats in user profiles]

Comment: Hooray for hats!

Comment: No mobile web love?

Comment: @cde I don't do mobile web.  I'm guessing that performance is more of a consideration there.